# How to boot my server by a live Ubuntu while the only access to this server is ssh connection

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, boot, partition, live-usb

I have bought additional disk space for my [VPS](https://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/29391.aspx), which is running Ubuntu 16.04.
[image]

to add the unallocated space to the root partition, I do think I have to boot the system by a live media to be able to add the unallocated space to the extended partition. If this is way I have to pass, How is it possible to boot this system by a live Ubuntu while my only access to it is just an ssh connection?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to. `growpart` is your friend, aswell as `resize2fs`. See https://askubuntu.com/a/937351/672946

Comment: Thank you so much, The "sudo growpart /dev/sda 2" which means Extend partition 2 in /dev/sda to fill empty space until end of disk or next partitiong included the unallocated partition to extended partition, so now on am able to resize it by Gparted

Answer (score 0):

Panki's idea is right; [growpart](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/growpart.1.html) can stretch your ext4 partition to fit the contiguous space available without your physical presence or a reboot from installation media.

First, run `sudo growpart --help` to confirm you have it already; if you don't then run `sudo apt install cloud-utils`.

However, please back up your data and configuration first! Use your normal backup method for the data; for the partition table, use [sfdisk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/sfdisk.8.html) {drive} {partition}, a lá: `sfdisk -d /dev/sda2 > partition_bak.dmp` before you run `sudo growpart /dev/sda 2` and `resize2fs /dev/sda2` to first enlarge the partition, then the filesystem.